# ViewPager extending PagerAdapter is not able to set view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My code for this class is unable to show view at the **0th position** and is also showing irrelevant data sometime. This view pager is attached with a `tablayout`.
I want to know why this is happening and if there is some other way to handle `viewpager` extending `PagerAdapter`.I will be happy if I will come to know about some another class relevant to `PagerAdapter` but without using Fragment.

```
 public class JobcardListViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements IWebServiceAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    List<TabLayoutDetails> tabLayoutDetailsList;
    ActiveJobCardListResponse activeJobCardListResponse;
    Activity activity;
    View itemView;
    WebService webService;

    public JobcardListViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<TabLayoutDetails> tabLayoutDetailsList) {

        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.tabLayoutDetailsList = tabLayoutDetailsList;
        webService = new WebService();

    }

    public JobcardListViewPagerAdapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabLayoutDetailsList.size(); // value of tabLayoutDetailsList.size() returning 10;


    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabLayoutDetailsList.get(position).getDescription();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.active_job_card_list_view_pager_adapter, container, false);

        GetActiveJobCardList(position);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }


}
```

Comment: So `GetActiveJobCardList(position);` isn't working? You should show that method

Comment: Thanks for your reply I am updating it now.